# Symfony2 form collections limit

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a `Course` entity, which has many `CourseSessions`. `CourseSession` can be **active** or **passed**.

How can I render only **active** `CourseSessions` and save relations with the **passed** `CourseSessions` on the `Course` edit page?

Now I render all `CourseSessions` but when `CourseSession` counts more than 50, the page renders very slow.

Can anyone help me?

UPDATE 1:

```
class CourseType {
    $builder->add('sessions', 'collection', array(
        'label' => false,
        'type' => new CourseSessionType(), // <- here I want to pass only active Sessions
        'allow_add' => true,
        'allow_delete' => true,
        'prototype' => true,
        'prototype_name' => '__name__'
    ))
}

class CourseSessionType {
    // multiple CourseSession fields
}

// Course edit page
<div id="courseSessions" data-prototype="{{macros.course_session_prototype(form.sessions, 'Remove Session', true)|escape }}">
    {% do form.sessions.setRendered %}
    {% for widget in form.sessions.children %}
        {{ macros.course_session_prototype(widget, 'Remove Session', false) }}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

UPDATE 2:

How can I map my `'type' => new CourseSessionType()` with `getActiveCourseSessions()` and `setActiveCourseSessions()`? I think it will help me.

Comment: Symfony does not have any default 'edit' page for entities. Are you using Sonata? If so, you still would need to provide far more information on what widget you are using and ideally the relevant bits of code. I'm gonna guess that what you need to do is create custom getActiveCourseSessions and setActiveCourseSessions functions and then set have the sonata edit form render 'activeCourseSessions' instead of 'courseSessions'.

Comment: "Symfony does not have any default 'edit' page for entities." I mean Course update page - one from CRUD actions. I'm using symfony for sure.

Comment: You need to provide more information. This question does not contain sufficient information to help. Are you talking about the code generated by using the command "generate:doctrine:crud"? Perhaps this would help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497133/directly-access-a-form-fields-value-when-overriding-widget-in-a-twig-template

Comment: 1) I created manually custom page, where I can edit the course
2) When Course contains more then 50 Sessions (active and passed) my page loads wery slow.
Question: how can I render only active sessions?

P.S. what exact did not you understand, and what i should provide??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm glat to tell you that I found the solution!

I added in my `Course` entity a `$showOnlyActiveSessions` property and changed `getSessions()` method

```
class Course
{
    /**
     * Show only active sessions flag
     * @var bool
     */
    private $showOnlyActiveSessions = false;

    // other properties

    /**
     * Get course sessions
     * @return CourseSession []
     */
    public function getSessions()
    {
        $sessions = $this->sessions;
        if ($this->getShowOnlyActiveSessions()) {
            return array_filter($sessions->toArray(), function($session) {
                return !$session->isPast();
            });
        }
        return $this->sessions;
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getShowOnlyActiveSessions()
    {
        return $this->showOnlyActiveSessions;
    }

    /**
     * @param bool $boolValue
     */
    public function setShowOnlyActiveSessions($boolValue)
    {
        $this->showOnlyActiveSessions = $boolValue;
    }
}
```

and now, when I need to get only active sessions i do the following in my controller:

```
public function editAction(Request $request, Course $course)
{
    $course->setShowOnlyActiveSessions(true);

    $editForm = $this->createEditForm($course);
    $editForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($editForm->isValid()) {
        // handle and persist form
    }
    return $this->redirectToRoute('course_list');
}
```

I hope it'll be helpful for somebody.

Answer (score 0):

try to set the name of the field accordingly to the method to map using `active_course_sessions` or shorter if you name your methods `Course::getActiveSessions()` and `Course::setActiveSessions()` it could be done like this :

```
class CourseType {
    $builder->add('active_sessions', 'collection', array(
        'label' => false,
        'type' => new CourseSessionType(),
        'allow_add' => true,
        'allow_delete' => true,
        'prototype' => true,
        'prototype_name' => '__name__'
    ));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I tried this approach and it doesn't work.

Comment: have you also add the property ? (`private $activeSessions;`) You also need to to set in the constructor `$this->activeSession = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();`

Comment: No, I haven't. I thought that it is a bad idea because for other parts of our application there is no differents between `session` and `active session` it is the same entities.